# How to disable touch event?

Tags: java, android, android-event

I have an Application, in one of `myActivity` i am using `webView`. With some type of tablets i have the problem of double touch. a touch event in My JS and other in Android. I can't remove the touch event in JS because with some tablets. i ought to implement it.  So I would like to Stop the Android touch events for this Activity and it's child and not for all the application. I tried

```
public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        view.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try overriding the onTouchEvent for each view and ignore the user input?

Comment: can yoou give me an example, please?

Comment: This is for onTouchListener - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html and this is an article on handling touch events in Android- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html

Comment: can you explain what happen exactly ? you talk about "the other event in Android". if you identify it, you should be able to ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to ignore a touch event on a webview is quite simple,  just do :

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false; //returns true if you wan't also ignore the js touch events
    }
});
```

The thing is, I'm not sure the triggered event are from the webview or another view, you need to define it so you can set this same **OnTouchListener** on the appropriate view.

Comment: it works for disable touch event, but it is not what i am loooking for.